# Barnyard2 / Snort - Mysql support issue

Tags: mysql, snort

I'm facing a problem, mysql support on barnyard2. It says this:

> Barnyard2 spooler: Event cache size set to [2048]  Log directory =
>   /var/log/barnyard2 ERROR database: 'mysql' support is not compiled
>   into this build of barnyard2
>
> ERROR: If this build of barnyard2 was obtained as a binary
>   distribution (e.g., rpm, or Windows), then check for alternate builds
>   that contains the necessary 'mysql' support.
>
> If this build of barnyard2 was compiled by you, then re-run the the
>   ./configure script using the '--with-mysql' switch. For non-standard
>   installations of a database, the '--with-mysql=DIR' syntax may need to
>   be used to specify the base directory of the DB install.

But I have tried to install mysql support, with the string `--with-mysql etc etc` and everything worked fine, I could do the installation but anytime I try to start barnyard2 I get always this error.

Libmysqlclient is already installed at new version, I have checked.

What can I do?